# APR Problem - How much finance should I take out based on a credit of £550?

Tags: finance

I'm having a problem putting my mathematics degree to good use. A friend of mine wants me to work out the following problem for him:

A motorbike costs £14,000. I will receive a "sweetener" from the motorcycle company of £550 if I take out any amount of finance (£14K, £10K, or £5K - they will give you £550 however much finance you take out.)

With 5.9% APR, he wants to know how much finance he can take out, so that the cost of the finance is mitigated by the £550 sweetener, i.e. the finance costs him nothing.

I came up with the following solution:

$5.9%$ APR is equivalent to $0.01616%$ DPR (daily percentage rate)

Hence your interest rate is 100.01616% per day, or 1.0001616 as a decimal.

So we can write $b(1.0001616)^{365n}$ to express the total amount you will be paying back based on the amount borrowed, $b$, for $n$ number of years.

If we subtract the original amount borrowed $b$ from this, we will have how much interest we are paying for the finance:

$b(1.0001616)^{365n}-b = b(1.0001616^{365n}-1)$

And we want this to be the same as the sweetener so it effectively costs nothing, hence:

$b(1.0001616^{365n}-1) = 550$

which when rearranged, gives me  $b=2840$

However, when I use an APR calculator, I'm told if I borrow £2840 for 36 months at 5.9%, the cost of the loan is £265... not the £550 I was expecting it to be.

Can anyone tell me where my solution has gone wrong? any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Doug

Answer (score 1):

For 3 years the composite interest is 9.1%. If you finance £6040 you are going to pay £6590 in three years, paying £183.06 per month.

Comment: Please explain how you arrived at 19%. Also please explain how you arrived at £2931.
And why when I use an online APR calculator does it say that £6000 (approx.) borrowed at 5.9% APR for 3 years will cost £550 (approx.) which doesn't agree with your figure?

Comment: I overlooked the question, now the figures are correct.

Comment: Cool. I suppose, technically you should factor in the future value of the 550, but with rates so low, it won't matter much.